# How it could be happen that "org.eclipse.core.runtime" is needed in MANIFEST.MF?

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin

I've created simple "plug-in" project.
But when I tried to create plug-in class which extends "org.eclipse.core.runtime.Plugin"
it said that the name couldn't be resolved. I've added "org.eclipse.core.runtime"
to Require-Bundle,

but wondering how it could be that I HAVE to add it to Require-Bundle?

Isn't it should be loaded irrelevant to MANIFEST.MF? Or is it a new feature of Eclipse?

Comment: Just get that MANIFEST.MF is an OSGI thing, not Eclipse.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In OSGi you have to declare dependency on every bundle or package you consume. The only thing that's directly accessible are basic JRE classes and OSGi API itself.